# Animate image view in a pattern

Tags: android, android-animation

i wanned to move a imageview from source(Bee) to destination(Flowers)
like in this image: http://postimg.org/image/np069wui3/

but i cant get the result
i m doing this to move it

```
for (int i = 0; i < List_Position.size(); i++) {
                            int[] posXY = new int[2];
                            img_main[List_Position.get(i)].getLocationOnScreen(posXY);
                            int x = posXY[0]+img_main[List_Position.get(i)].getWidth()/2;
                            int y = posXY[1]+img_main[List_Position.get(i)].getHeight()/2;
                            Position_X.add(x);
                            Position_Y.add(y);
                        }
```

// to animate an image view i did this

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(Position_X.get(0), Position_X.get(7), Position_Y.get(0), Position_Y.get(7));
                            animation.setDuration(3000);
                            img_main[Start_Pos].startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fromXDelta` and `fromYDelta` in constructor of `TranslateAnimation` are `delta` from the original location of the view. I think your `Position_X.get(0)` is an absolute position, not a `delta`.

Comment: so how can i get image view delta value

Comment: Use getLocationOnScreen to get the original location.  `Position_X.get(0) - originalX` is the delta.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link : [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views)

Here you have the translation coordinate x,y vakues so this is simplest way you can translate view by,

```
yourView.animate().x(targetX).y(targetY).setDuration(2000);
```

Hope this helped!